# Нужно сделать, чтобы точки стояли вплотную

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
messages_count = 10
for i in reversed(range(2, messages_count + 1)):
print('- Анфиса, есть ли новые письма?')
print("- Непрочитанных писем: ",i,".")
print("Я прочитал одно, и их осталось",i-1,".")
print("- Анфиса, есть ли новые письма?")
print("- Одно непрочитанное письмо.")
print('Я прочитал его. И нет больше писем!')
```

Comment: Откройте для себя форматирование строк: https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/04_data_structures/4b_string_format.html

Answer (score 1):

При перечислении через `,` автоматически ставятся пробелы. Если Вы хотите их убрать используйте `+`.

```
messages_count = 10
for i in reversed(range(2, messages_count + 1)):
    print('- Анфиса, есть ли новые письма?')
    print("- Непрочитанных писем: ", i + ".")
    print("Я прочитал одно, и их осталось", i-1 + ".")
    print("- Анфиса, есть ли новые письма?")
    print("- Одно непрочитанное письмо.")
    print('Я прочитал его. И нет больше писем!')
```